# gtkmm entry missing keys on signal_key_press_event

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

So I have been experimenting with the Gtkmm, as I want to migrate some of my code to C++ and I figured it would be easier.

I used to be able to use something that looks like so in C:

```
    g_signal_connect(entry, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(receiveKeyPressed), NULL);
```

But it seems when I try to use the similar system in Gtkmm:

```
    entry->signal_key_pressed().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(*receiveKeyPressed) );
```

It entirely misses all keyboard presses except for the shift keys and tab, etc.

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Inside your widget, have you tried signal_key_press_event().connect(...) instead?

Comment: Haven't tried that. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your [handler](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a4b64421cad754fbd49ae17cbfe4814d0) as first:

> Flags: Run Last

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();

    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::Entry entry;
    window.add(entry);

    entry.signal_key_press_event().connect([&](GdkEventKey* event)->bool{
            std::cout<<"pressed: "<<std::hex<<event->keyval<<" "<<std::hex<<event->state<<std::endl; 
            return false; //to propagate the event further
        }, false); //run before other handlers (from entry)

    window.show_all();
    return app->run(window);
}
```